# Unable to import dlib in python 3 due to ImportError

Tags: python, dlib

When I try to import dlib in python3 (MacOsX), I get the following:

```
>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dlib import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dlib/dlib.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyClass_Type
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/boost-python/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/opt/boost-python/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
```

Earlier it was importing properly but suddenly it has stopped working.
What should I do now?

Comment: libboost is not installed. Install libboost for python 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe it could help.

Install Anaconda2 32/64 python 2 or Install Anaconda3 32/64 python 3

It Depends on System Information

Along the way you *must check all the options* ignore the **red text**

Then wait till installation completed ...

Open CMD admin when finish installed

Make sure that the anaconda-python is configured in CMD admin *Type: python*

This will come out:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>python Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)|
>   (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Next is to install: dlib

*conda install -c conda-forge dlib = (version optional)*

(click yes if ok)

Same as OpenCV:

*conda install -c conda-forge opencv = (version optional)*

(click yes if ok)

When all the package is completely installed, *then you must Reboot it.*

go to CMD admin again

type "python"

import dlib

import cv2

then you're done!

Comment: Can you provide an explanation along with the code?